# Getting confused between the lines of drop(columns) in numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

What is the difference between

```
np.array(df.drop(['label'],1))
```

and

```
np.array(df['label'])
```

Answer (score 1):

`drop` deletes the column from the dataframe, so you're getting the array of all columns but the one you dropped. `np.array(df['label'])` gives you just the label column. See also the [drop documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html).